# 502 Bad Gateway with Nginx

Tags: nginx

When I clicked on this link `http://localhost:8094/blast/get_sequences.cgi?database=db/Nbv5.1trPrm&hit_count=1&alignment_seq_1=Nbv5.1tr6212914%20RNA-dependent%20RNA%20polymerase%202%20(probable)` I got

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

My config file for nginx (default) is:

```
# Default server configuration
#

error_log /var/log/blast.log error;
access_log /var/log/blast.log;

fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

client_max_body_size 10M;

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

  # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
  #
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  #Rules for blast
  location /blast/ {
    location ~ \.cgi($|.*) {
      gzip off;
      autoindex on;
      include fastcgi_params;
      #fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/blast/;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
  }
}

  #Rules for sequenceserver
  location /sequenceserver/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4567/;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_connect_timeout 8;
      proxy_read_timeout 180;
  }
}
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: This makes no sense. You are browser localhost:8094 but your configuration does not mention port 8094 at all.

Comment: The 8094 port came from the `docker-compose.yml` file. How is it possible to get the logs out of docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you don't have your application software running which uses `/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket` for communication between nginx and itself.